# Install error: Package is invalid. Info: "The backgroundscript "back.js" could not be loaded."

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When I load my chrome-app locally I have no issues. Beofore it was also fully functional published, but I had to update the code a bit, and now I'm getting an error that I simply can't find the source of (or any ressources that has even had the same issue).

The error message I am getting is

> Install error: Package is invalid. Info: "The backgroundscript  "back.js" could not be loaded.".

The manifest file:

```
{
    "name": "x",
    "version": "1.1.332",
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["back.js"]
    },
    "permissions": ["https://redacted.com/*", "http://www.redacted.com/manual.php",
    "tabs", "storage", "webNavigation"],
    "browser_action": {}
}
```

The back.js looks like this:

```
   chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,{file: "magic.js"}); 
      info
        var newURL = "http://www.redacted.php";      chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL }); 

          });

   chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(tab) {
     chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,{file: "targetPage.js"});     }, {url: [{urlMatches : 'http://www.redacted.php'}]});
```

I'm zipping the .crx file together with the manifest-file and upload it.

Comment: Make sure your zip or crx file doesn't have any directories inside.

Comment: @wOxxOm I just checked - It only contains the 3 javascripts (back.js, magic.js & targetPage.js) + the manifest.

Comment: @wOxxOm https:// we.tl/t-GKmRHSh6tl does this link work?

Comment: You need to upload a zip file, not crx. Currently the web store puts your crx file inside a dummy extension as the only file besides the manifest as you can see in CRXViewer: https://puu.sh/CGd8S/86e951d1e6.png

Comment: @wOxxOm Oh wauw - what a stupid mistake :). It works now! 
So how do I do this. Tell you to create an answer I can accept or :D ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to w0xx0m

It was a rather stupid mistake:

> You need to upload a zip file, not crx. Currently the web store puts your crx file inside a dummy extension as the only file besides the manifest as you can see in CRXViewer